# How to delete my BlockChain.info account?

Tags: blockchain.info

Is there any way to delete a BlockChain.info account? I am not able to find any such option in settings.

Comment: Is this on blockchain.info? If yes I suggest you contact the site's support.

Comment: No, there's no way. But you can vote on https://blockchain.uservoice.com/forums/152743-general-ideas/suggestions/2651836-option-to-delete-account